# How to update a trained Word2vec model in gensim with same parameters

Tags: parameters, gensim, word2vec

I 've been some trouble updating a model from gensim. I use the following command to create the model.

`model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentences,size=100, window=20, min_count=10, workers=24, iter=200, callbacks=[epoch_saver])`
and to save the model, I used:

`model.save(type+"/"+"word2vec_"+name+"_"+type+"."+version)`

As far as I remember, the first step, when training a model, is to create a vocab. Anyway, I had to stop the training on iter=147. So, now I want to load and continue training. This is how I load the model:

`model = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load("encoded_op_op/temporary_model/word2vec.model")`

But how do I use train() method to continue update ? I am trying :

`model = model.train(sentences, epochs=53, callbacks=[epoch_saver])`

but it gives an error:

> You must specify either total_examples or total_words, for proper job parameters updationand progress
> calculations. The usual value is total_examples=model.corpus_count.

Anyway, where could I define the same parameters used when creating the model: size=100, window=20, min_count=10, workers=24. Ok. i believe size is already defined. but what about workers ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

By supplying `sentences` directly in the original instantiation call, you essentially asked that one call to also do the `build_vocab()` & `train()` steps automatically using those `sentences`.

While you *can* always send more training examples to a model, that's not a usually-expected operation, and so requires care/expertise to do right, and still might break some usual assumptions of the SGD training optimization. This is especially so after a previous run may have been interrupted in the middle of its planned count-of-training-epochs.

The model has within it your original parameters, and some cached values from the initial vocabulary survey (like `workers`, etc). But when you're calling `train()` yourself, you need to be explicit about how much data you're sending - hence the error you're getting.

You can very-simply avoid the error by providing just what it requests – using a value cached inside the model. For example (but **don't** do this, for reasons explained below):

```py
model.train(sentences, epochs=53, callbacks=[epoch_saver], 
            total_examples=model.corpus_count)
```

(Note: you also **don't** want to assign the return value, which is just some statistics, into `model`, or you'll lose your reference to the actual model.)

This supplies what the error requests & thus prevents the exception - but still isn't quite doing the right thing.

That's because the original training was 147/200ths of the way through the normal linear learning-rate decay, from the starting `alpha` of `0.025` to its ending negligible `min_alpha` value. But if you just run the above code, you're *restarting the learning rate at `0.025`, completely unlike what would have happened, if the original training had continued*.

Instead, to put the internal learning-rate roughly back where it was mid-training at the 147th epoch, you can use an optional parameter to `train()`, `start_alpha`, like so:

```
model.train(model.train(sentences, epochs=53, callbacks=[epoch_saver], 
            total_examples=model.corpus_count,
            start_alpha=(model.min_alpha + (53/200 * (model.alpha - model.min_alpha)))
```

Then, you'll be closely appromating what *would* have happened, if the original training had reached its last 53 epochs.

However, as a general observation, you should probably just restart the training from scratch. It's much simpler and less error-prone.

But if in fact it was so time-consuming you feel you need to resume-from-a-partial-training, then it's odd that you're using so many training epochs. With adequate, large data – the kind that might take hours to run – more typical `iter` values would be `5` (the default) to `10` or `20`.

Larger values are only typical if your data is very small/thin. Despite the fact that word2vec doesn't work as well on such smaller data, you can get partially-sensible results with many more training cycles. But then, the overall training duration is unlikely to be so long you have to do such complicated partial-work resumption.

Also: with a `sentences` argument that provides a pure-Python sequence as the corpus, you likely won't be getting very good throughput & CPU-core utilization with `workers=24`. Some bottlenecks in the way the implementation passes data between threads, and the limitation of the Python Global Interpreter Lock (GIL), means the threads will often be blocking each other from making good progress.

Typically, even if your machine has 16, 32, 64, or more cores, that pathway reaches maximum throughput with only about 8-12 worker threads, at most. (And you'll get the best throughput is you ensure your `sentences` is as simple as possible, either an already-tokenized-in-memory list-of-lists, or a simple reading of space-delimited tokens from disk – but not repeated regex preprocessing/tokenization.)

If you can write your corpus to a single file, with each sentence on a line, and all tokens pre-split by a single space, you can instead use the newer `corpus_file` option to specify that file, and then a number of `workers` up to the actual number of cores in your machine will all do their own non-blocking work, achieving much higher throughput/CPU-utilization.

Comment: Here is output of gensim after vocab_build:

`collected 264475612 word types from a corpus of 3519706628 raw words and 56707 sentences`

Is this large enough ?

Comment: The real test is: are you getting sufficient/stable results from fewer `epochs`, or does increasing the # of training passes  cause noticeable improvements? But yes, a corpus of 3.5 billion raw words would normally be pretty good, especially for typical natural-language training. However, I see that you have **264 million** unique words. That's not typical for natural language. (Even the giant `GoogleNews` word-vector set Google released has only 3 million words & phrases.) That implies you're using word2vec on some other sort of data, thus many typical rules-of-thumb won't necessary apply. …

Comment: Word2vec may still be helpful, but working with data that might not have the same vocabularyrange or word-distribution or co-occurrence patterns could mean more tinkering with parameters will be helpful, or more preprocessing helpful - the "best" options may be further from the usual defaults. Especially relevant considerations could include: how many words remain after applying your `min_count=10` setting? What's the eventual use /evaluation-of-word-vector quality going to be? …

Comment: Also, 3.5 billion divided by 57K 'sentences' gives an average sentence-length of 61K tokens. There's an internal gensim `Word2Vec` implementation limit, at least through version 3.8.3, that only the 1st 10K tokens in any one text are trained-on. So I can see from those stats that much, indeed **most**, of your corpus must be in larger-than-10K texts, and thus ignored-by-training. You'll want to break your 'sentences' into no-more-than-10k-token groupings to avoid that from happening. (And compared to your setup-so-far, that'll mean slower training, but better because of more real varied data.)

Comment: Answering: 



`effective_min_count=10 retains 3782375 unique words (1% of original 264475612, drops 260693237)`


`effective_min_count=10 leaves 3203281050 word corpus (91% of original 3519706628, drops 316425578)`

BTW: Thanks a lot for explanations !

Comment: What's the eventual use /evaluation-of-word-vector quality going to be? I am trying to create an assembly language model based on mnemonic and operands. I will use it to model types of programs.